# Default values of RAM

Tags: verilog, hdl

I writing in Verilog HDL for synthesis and I want to instantiate a DUAL PORT RAM with default values (zeros), how can do it?

Thanks, Netanel

Comment: Rams are not something that exist to verilog. The way to get a ram is to write some verilog that looks like how a ram behaves, and then use synthesizer-specific methods to tell the synthesizer to synthesize the logic block as a ram. But there's no such thing as a 'ram' in verilog language.

Comment: If it is for an ASIC your process vendor might have libraries that include dual port ram.

Comment: No, it for XILINX Virtex-7 FPGA device

Comment: Then use Core Generator for instantiating a dual port RAM. By default, it is initialized with 0's

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned Virtex-7 - look in the [Xilinx Synthesis manual](http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/sw_manuals/xilinx2013_2/ug901-vivado-synthesis.pdf) for examples of how to write Verilog that infers a memory block.

In Appendix C you can find this code:

```
// Dual-Port Block RAM with Two Write Ports
// File: HDL_Coding_Techniques/rams/rams_16.v
module v_rams_16 (clka,clkb,ena,enb,wea,web,addra,addrb,dia,dib,doa,dob);
  input clka,clkb,ena,enb,wea,web;
  input [9:0] addra,addrb;
  input [15:0] dia,dib;
  output [15:0] doa,dob;
  reg [15:0] ram [1023:0];
  reg [15:0] doa,dob;
always @(posedge clka) begin if (ena)
begin
  if (wea)
    ram[addra] <= dia;
    doa <= ram[addra];
  end
end
always @(posedge clkb) begin if (enb)
begin
  if (web)
    ram[addrb] <= dib;
    dob <= ram[addrb];
  end
end
endmodule
```

I'm not a Verilogger, but I'm sure you can tweak the `ram` declaration to make it initialise with all zeros.

Comment: To initialise you could add a reset, or write all 0s during a startup sequence.

Comment: @Morgan: you could do that, but that's not how FPGA block rams work - they are initialised at configuration time, which is before the reset is operative (kind of like you suggest, in a startup sequence, but not under runtime control of the user).  Reset cannot clear the whole array in a single tick, so if you write code for that, the ram will be implemented in registers and muxes, which gets big, fast!

Comment: Good point. I assumed they would have an async active low reset.